# How to change id to value in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Have an object that I received from server. in that look

[image]
I need to change all "id" to name "value"
Try to parse to JSON change it and convert to the array, but have very bad results

```
var x = nextProps.campus;
        var fff =  JSON.stringify(x);

        var res = fff.replace(/name/g, "value");

        var arr = [];
        for (var prop in res) {
            arr.push(res[prop]);
            }
```

in result I need like this

```
var options = [
    { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
    { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
];
```

Comment: please add the object in literal notation.

Comment: `data.map(({id,name})=>({value:id,name}))` will do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var body = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "school_test_1"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "school_test_2"
}];

var options = body.map((x) => ({value:x.id,label:x.name}));

console.log(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the array ach assign the new property with the old value and delete the proerty then.

```js
var options = [{ name: 'one', label: 'One' }, { name: 'two', label: 'Two' }];

options.forEach(function (o) {
    o.value = o.name;
    delete o.name;
});

console.log(options);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with lodash something like this:

```
var myData= [{
      id: 1,
      name: "school_test_1"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "school_test_2"
    }]

var changeLabel= {
  id: 'value',
  name: 'label'
};


var newArray = _.map(myData ,function(obj) {
  return _.mapKeys(obj, function(value, key) {
    return changeLabel[key];
  });
});
```

Comment: OP's not asking for lodash

Comment: sorry, this can be usfel for you:
stackoverflow.com/questions/27158371/renaming-keys-in-javascript-array

Comment: Why are you sending this link ? I am just saying that OP did not ask for loadash answers

Comment: the link is not about lodash i said tha can help you and that's not  the good way how we answer .
good luck